# Java Session, o JsessionID muda

Tags: java, session, servlet

Estou com uma página web que faz requisições a um Servlet via Ajax.

Na servlet eu crio uma session para manter o funcionário autenticado e para identificá-lo dentro do sistema.

No entanto, quando saio do sistema, coloco as telas Html/css/javascript em outra porta e tento usar o sistema, toda vez que é feito um novo request em outro servlet, meu JsessionID se perde e é criado outro.

Por que isso acontece?